# How to remove all reactions of a message using discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want my bot to send a message that clears all reactions of the message after 10 seconds. How can I do that? I can't seem to find anything on the internet.

Here's my code:

```py
import discord
from time import sleep

TOKEN = "my-discord-token"
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message == "test":
        msg_id = await message.channel.send("Test")
        sleep(10)
        {What should I put here?}

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Thanks!!

Comment: You appear to have not searched for how to clear reactions for a discord message. I found plenty of info online for that. Please do basic research before posting here. Or demonstrate what you *have* researched, and explain in detail what you tried and what did or didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should use `await asyncio.sleep(10)` instead of `sleep(10)`. Discord library depends on [asynchronous programming](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/) and when you use `sleep(10)` from the `time` library it freezes your entire code. This results in stoping your bot from handling other tasks properly.
2. You have to change `if message...` to `if message.content`. Message object contains not only the message text but other information too. You have to use `message.content` to get only the text part that you need.
3. And for clearing reactions you can use [`clear_reactions()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=clear%20reactions#discord.Message.clear_reactions).

```py
import asyncio # add this import

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content == "test": # you have to use `message.content`
        msg = await message.channel.send("Test")
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        await msg.clear_reactions()
```

Comment: `discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50003): Cannot execute action on a DM channel` do you have any idea to clear the reactions inside a DM ?

Comment: @Test Unfortunately, I think you can't. You can't clear someone's else reaction in a DM as you don't have permission for it. If it's your message you can delete it, resend it and add reaction. Check out [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53525148/how-to-remove-reaction-in-a-dm-using-discord-py) for more info.